# why is this a spinlock

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Trying to understand the following implementation of a barrier. The goal is that `_entry` can only be entered once.The only part I don't get is the use of `%rip`. Apparently it spins if `mutex(%rip)=0`, but why is that?

```
.section data
mutex:
    .long 0

.section text
...
_entry:
    xor %rax, %rax
    xchgl mutex(%rip), %rax
    cmp %rax, 0
    jnz _entry
```

Comment: It's just using rip-relative addressing for position independent code. Would work just the same with absolute addressing, if PIC was not a requirement. PS: it's broken though, you want to set it to `1` not `0`. Not to mention it won't even assemble since you can't load a `long` into `%rax`.

Comment: @Jester so is `mutex(%rip)` the same as `mutex`, or is that actually address the first byte of the next instruction?

Comment: It's the same (it will access `mutex`), but the assembler will generate an offset relative to the next instruction in the machine code.

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a spinlock because it basically:

1. keeps looping without calling a "yield" syscall (in other words, it doesn't ask for a context switch)
2. uses an "atomic" operation to make sure that the "lock variable" has the desired value in order to break the loop or not.

The `mutex(%rip)` is the RIP-relative (relative instruction-pointer) addressing. It's just a variable. Could be any other variable.

THe pseudo-code for this would be something like this:

```
_entry:
    x = 0;
    swap(mutex, x);
    if (x != 0)
        goto _entry;
```

But with highlight to the `swap()`, that is the `xchg` (exchange operation). In turn it is an ATOMIC operation. This is what guarantees that 2 different threads will not modify this "lock variable" (`mutex`) at the same time.

As an EXTRA useful information:

- **Why it's not a mutex?** Because it doesn't invoke a syscall for a context switch in the operating system.
- **Does it mean there's no context switch happening?** No, this is not true. Context switch WILL happen anyway, however it will happen in the time the operating system decides by itself, instead of the explict invoked by this routine. There's a maximum limit the operating system gives for each thread.

NOTE: The "lock variable" is called `mutex` in this example. But in fact it depends on the vocabulary you are using. Most of the time this would NOT be considered a "mutex". A lock can by done with a mutex or a spinlock or an hybrid of mutex+spinlock. But the example above is NOT the hybrid thing. The variable name should be something else besides `mutex`.

Comment: The OP's problem seems to be that of what the RIP is all about in the one instruction. Maybe I have misinterpreted what he meant but he did say _The only part I don't get is the use of %rip_

Comment: Also, as I pointed out, writing `0` into it won't make it a mutex ... it's value will never change so everybody will be allowed to enter the critical section whenever they please. Not much of a mutex ;)